# Wrap div around img width and keep div 100% high

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing an issue where I need to position an element on top of a image on a specific place on the image (lets say 20% from top and 30% from left).

My proposed solution to this was to wrap the image in a div with `relative` position and then place the element with position `absolute` top and left - simple. But after many attempts I cant get this to work and it seems to be different behaviour in the browsers.

When you load the fiddle below the dummy image will work when you load the page, BUT, when you start expand or shrink the result-window in Chrome or Firefox you will start to see the red `div` that's containing the image. This causes the dot to move away from its intended point. This does not happen in Safari.

So the question is: How can I keep the image tightly wrapped at all times?

**UPDATE**: In response to answer: The div containing the image must 100% of the size of its parent, it cannot be larger or smaller then that.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/12q26xu7/2/

```css
html,
body {
  height: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.child-wrapper {
  height: 50%;
}
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.image-wrap img {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.image-wrap .point {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 30%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #000000;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="child-wrapper">
    <div class="image-wrap">
      <img class="viewer__image" src="http://dummyimage.com/300">
      <div class="point"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In basics, you want three different things:

- Let an image (or the wrapping `div`) get the height of a parent `div`
- Keep the image's aspect ratio
- Resize the image based on the `viewport-height` and `-width`

As we've tried out together, we couldn't fix this with only `CSS`, which is why I came up with the following idea: What if we get the height of the `parent div`, and apply that height to the image?

Which is why I came with the following solution:

**OPTION 1**

Adding the following piece of jQuery (and of course a jQuery-library), the ratio of the image is kept when resizing the window.

```
$(function() {
  var height = $('.child-wrapper').height();
  $( ".image-wrap, .image-wrap img" ).css('height', height + 'px');
});

$( window ).resize(function() {
  var height = $('.child-wrapper').height();
  $( ".image-wrap, .image-wrap img" ).css('height', height + 'px');
});
```

You also have to get rid of all the dimensions stated in the CSS for `.image-wrap` and `.image-wrap img`, so you're left with this:

```
.image-wrap {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

.image-wrap img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/12q26xu7/27/)

**OPTION 2**

If you want, you could also throw in a `box-sizing: border-box;`, so the border is becoming part of the div, instead of being around it. However, the image will overflow, which means you'd have to remove 2 pixels (or however thick your border is) from the image. You can easily do that with the jQuery below, which looks a lot like the one in the top but is edited to work with `box-sizing`.

```
$(function() {
  var height = $('.child-wrapper').height();
  $( ".image-wrap" ).css('height', height + 'px');
  $( '.image-wrap img').css('height', height -2 + 'px');
});
    
$( window ).resize(function() {
  var height = $('.child-wrapper').height();
  $( ".image-wrap" ).css('height', height + 'px');
  $( '.image-wrap img').css('height', height -2 + 'px');
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/12q26xu7/26/)

Both these examples need tweaking so they work exactly like you want it to work in your project.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reponse but in the fiddle the image wrapper now goes outside the child container. It has to be 100% of its height

Comment: Option 2 is working for me in my "real" project after some small tweaks! Thank you for your help! Note that the JS answer from @Pete is probably working as well since they do about the same thing. Also note that Option 1 in this answer is not accepted only 2:)

Answer (score 2):

Just make the height and width of you div `auto`:

```
.image-wrap {
    position:relative;
    height: auto;
    width:auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background: red;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/12q26xu7/3/)

**EDIT**

As per your updated question, for keeping 100% height but aspect ratio width, I don't think you can do this with pure css so with the following bit of js should do it:

```
$('.image-wrap').each(function () {
    var wrap = $(this),
        image = wrap.children('img:eq(0)'),
        ratio = image.width() / image.height();

    wrap.data('ratio', ratio);
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    $('.image-wrap').each(function () {
        var wrap = $(this),
            image = wrap.children('img:eq(0)'),
            width = image.height() * wrap.data('ratio');

        image.width(width);
        wrap.width(width);
    });
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/12q26xu7/24/)

Comment: Hi thanks but sorry. The image-wrap has to be 100% height of its parent. Sorry if I was unclear on this.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pure css, whilst keeping the images constraints.  This is the closest I came: http://jsfiddle.net/12q26xu7/23/.  The problem is that the inner image needs a width in order for the outer div to be able to resize to the images width when the page is resized

Comment: ok thank you for trying, but if I knew the image width beforehand could I give it a dynamic with and make the div size around that?